# Has anyone ever tried to derive gravitoelectromagnetic waves equation?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves, maxwell-equations, linearized-theory

Has anyone ever tried to derive [gravitoelectromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) waves equation? As we know, there is Maxwell-like equation in gravity. Has anyone here ever  formulated gravito electromagnetic waves equation using Maxwell-like equation in the same way with electromagnetism? If so,  I want to know the properties of that waves based on the equations. Is it same with gravitational waves?

I am actually working on this, but I still don't know the physical meaning of that waves.

Comment: Your link includes GEM's version of Maxwell's equations, from which you can obtain wave equations. However, the way $\rho,\,\mathbf{J}$ transform from one reference frame to the next is non-Lorentzian, as noted near the end.